# How to find first matching between arrays and format it

Tags: python, algorithm, search

I have basic list

```
['hello', 'how', 'you', 'doing', 'today']
```

And I want to compare other list to it.

if list like this

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'hello', 'how', 'you', 'doing', 'today']
```

algorithm should return

```
['hello', 'how', 'you', 'doing', 'today']
```

actually just find basic list in given list

Also given list can be like this

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'how', 'you', 'doing', 'today']
```

So as we can see in this example missing word **hello** so first matching is on position 1 on basic list. In this case return list should look like it

```
['*', 'how', 'you', 'doing', 'today']
```

What will be after first matching doesn't matter

So once again
**Example 1**

```
basic = ['hello', 'how', 'you', 'doing', 'today']
given = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'hello', 'how', 'you', 'doing', 'today']
output = ['hello', 'how', 'you', 'doing', 'today']
```

**Example 2**

```
basic = ['hello', 'how', 'you', 'doing', 'today']
given = ['how', 'you', 'doing', 'man']
output = ['*', 'how', 'you', 'doing', 'man']
```

**Example 3**

```
basic = ['hello', 'how', 'you', 'doing', 'today']
given = ['one', 'two', 'you', 'doing', 'man', 'yeaaaap']
output = ['*', '*', 'you', 'doing', 'man', 'yeaaaap']
```

My function look like this

```
def findFirstMatch(basic, given):
    for index, item in enumerate(basic):
        for i, el in enumerate(given):
            if basic[index].lower() == given[i].lower():
                return given[i:]
```

So right now I'm here it just remove elements before first match. It works correct if first match in on 1 position, but in **Example 2** it won't work correctly.

Comment: Ok, please show what you tried based on your research around this task and explain why it didn't work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have trouble understanding the question: I assume what you want to achieve is the following algorithm:

```
def match(basic, given):
    out = []

    # 1. go through list 'basic'
    # until you find the item in 'given'
    # append '*' to the output list for item you
    # do not find

    first_match = None
    for item in basic:
        if not item in given:
            out.append("*")
        else:
            first_match = item
            break
    if not first_match:
        return out

    # 2. now that we have found a match,
    # simply append the rest of 'given'

    index = given.index(first_match)
    out.extend(given[index:])

    return out
```

Test it:

```
match(['hello', 'how', 'you', 'doing', 'today'], ['one', 'two', 'three', 'hello', 'how', 'you', 'doing', 'today'])

# ['hello', 'how', 'you', 'doing', 'today']

match(['hello', 'how', 'you', 'doing', 'today'], ['how', 'you', 'doing', 'man'])

# ['*', 'how', 'you', 'doing', 'man']

match(['hello', 'how', 'you', 'doing', 'today'], ['one', 'two', 'you', 'doing', 'man', 'yeaaaap'])

# ['*', '*', 'you', 'doing', 'man', 'yeaaaap']
```

Reproduces your examples.